# Python modules compiled on Linux are vanishing

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cx-freeze, pygobject

I've used Python a lot on Windows, but I'm just starting to use it on Linux. Twice now, when installing cx_Freeze and installing PyGObject (aka PyGI), I've gone through the whole installation procedure in Terminal for the module in question, run Python, done an import test, which works, restarted Terminal, then gotten an ImportError when doing the same exact import test in the new Terminal window. I'm using pyenv to run Python 3.3.4 on Ubuntu 13.10. The various modules I've installed via pip seem to have no problems.

Further details:

**For cx_Freeze**, I'm using pyenv (with --enable-shared set) and it's set to use Python 3.3.4 in my ~/.bashrc file. So all I have to do is download and extract the tarball and run *python setup.py build* and *python setup.py install*. Then I run Python and test:

```
import cx_Freeze
```

and it works fine. But after I restart Terminal, I thereafter get "ImportError: No module named 'cx_Freeze'" when I try this test.

**For PyGObject**, which I'm using as a prerequisite for python3-keybinder, it's the same idea, except beforehand I have to install libgirepository1.0-dev and python3-cairo-dev and such, and I have to run *./configure*, *make*, *make install*. Immediately afterwards, I test this in Python:

```
import gi
```

and it works, but after I restart Terminal and repeat the test, I get an ImportError. (Theoretically, I should be able to do *pip install python3-gi* instead of doing all this stuff, but that doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu.)

Note that the version of Python that's running in all these cases is always the 3.3.4 version that's installed via pyenv, since I've set PYENV_VERSION to 3.3.4 in ~/.bashrc.

I have no idea why Python modules I install one minute are gone the next. Any ideas?

Comment: Since this is a Ubuntu thing, you might try asking on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: `pip install cx_Freeze` works on Ubuntu. Make sure that `which python` points to `python` from your python3.3 virtual environment.

Comment: This works for me: `pip install cx_Freeze --allow-external cx_Freeze --allow-unverified cx_Freeze`... still, I don't have a similar solution for PyGObject, and I don't know why the main "vanishing" problem is occurring. `which python` always gives me `/home/USERNAME/.pyenv/shims/python`, regardless of which version pyenv is set up to use.